# Loading a csv file using pandas

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I'm trying to load a csv file in google colab with pandas. I've tried many different ways now and I keep getting the same error message every time:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('C:/Users/renat/Documentos/pandas/pokemon_data.csv')
```

I've also tried with \ , and placing an 'r' before 'C:

The traceback error is

> FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:/Users/renat/Documentos/pandas/pokemon_data.csv'

Comment: Please include the traceback error.

Comment: Your Path says "Documentos". Are you sure this is correct

Comment: The traceback error is FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:/Users/renat/Documentos/pandas/pokemon_data.csv'

Comment: @Renata can you confirm that the file is actually in that location?

Comment: google calab doesn't have access to your local files

Comment: so is jupyter notebooks best for that?

Answer (score 0):

Try changing ur working directory first

Comment: How could I do that?

Comment: ```import os```  ```os.chdir('C:/Users/renat/Documentos/pandas')```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).